# Why is Tomcat unable to load class from WEB-INF/lib in this case?

Tags: java, spring-security, jackson, classloader, tomcat8

My application uses `jjwt` to to generate jwt tokens. jjwt in turn uses jackson. My WEB-INF/lib folder contains `jackson-core-2.8.10.jar` which I have verified contains `JsonProcessingException` class file. Still when I reach the particular point in the code I get a :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException

It is stranger still because when my friend builds and runs the same code in the same Tomcat version (Apache Tomcat/8.5.23) on Windows (I  am using Linux) it doesn't give an error. It doesn't even get an JsonProcessingException. The code runs through the same test cases without any issue. I am running java version "1.8.0_151" on my machine in case that is relevant.

The code segment:

```
String jwt_token = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, environment.getRequiredProperty("jwt.secret.key"))
                .compact();
```

When I try to put at try catch block around the Jwts call to catch the exception. I get the following error from my IDE:

> Error:(61, 11) java: exception com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Here's the stack trace from catalina.out:

```
2017-10-26 05:23:22.110 ERROR 7422 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/token] due to exception [com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
    at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder(Jwts.java:116) ~[jjwt-0.8.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at com.myapp.rest.security.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.myapp.rest.controller.JwtTokenController.generateJwt(JwtTokenController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

I believe this isn't a permissions issue because I have run tomcat with super user rights as well, it still gives an issue. I have reinstalled Tomcat. Doesn't help. I am at my wit's end with this. Our development process has been stalled for a week because we can't get on the same page.  I have prowled the internet for tens of hours trying to get a solution but nothing seems to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer to the issue myself. Turns out there was a jjwt 0.8 jar present in the jvm/ext folder (which  I must have placed some time ago, accidentally or intentionally - doesn't matter) so instead of resolving the jjwt jar from the WEB-INF/lib it was getting resolved at jvm/ext. I had previously noticed this but assumed the issue has nothing to do with this as I expected the other jar would be found elsewhere.

Turns out since the jjwt was present in jvm/ext folder the class loader was looking for its dependency in the same folder without looking for it anywhere else, like the WEB-INF/lib.

This is likely because class loaders work in hierarchies different loaders look at different levels. The Bootstrap loader in this instance looks for class files in jvm/ext. The WEB/INF/lib responsible loader is the WebappX loader. [Class loading in Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). So in short, I deleted the jar in jvm/ext and all is well in the world again.

Comment: You saved me so much trouble with this answer ! I found myself in a similar situation : a servlet's jar was placed in the tomcat/lib directory, but it required depencies placed in the WEB-INF/lib folder and didn't find them. As soon as I moved the servlet to WEB-INF/lib, the issue vanished.
Even after reading the documentation, I can't quite pinpoint why that kind of dependency can't be resolved... Anyway, thanks a lot for taking the time to document your finding and not keeping it to yourself !

Comment: @Ronan Thanks for your comment. I thought the class loading behaviour was really strange. Our project went nowhere but glad to see that it had some positive outcome as this side effect 3 years down the line!

Comment: many thanks, you save my day!